# How to execute this code in Ubuntu terminal

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal, bash-scripting

I am following a tutorial for Linux and I am a Windows user. I need to know, how can I execute code in Ubuntu terminal?

Here is what the exercise say:

> The directory will now have 4 keys - private/public pairs of ZSK and
>   KSK. We have to add the public keys which contain the DNSKEY record to
>   the zone file. The following for loop will do this.

```
for key in `ls Kexample.com*.key`
do
echo "\$INCLUDE $key">> example.com.zone
done
```

Is there a way to execute this code from terminal?

EDIT:
Following the answer from @Karl I get permission denied. I use `sudo` in normal commands like `mv` but how to deal with this in multiple lines and commands? here is my code listing:

```
x@mypc:/var/cache/bind$ for key in `ls Kcom*.key`
> do
> echo "\$INCLUDE $key" >> com.zone
> done
bash: com.zone: Permission denied
bash: com.zone: Permission denied
```

Comment: That's a bad tutorial if it tells you to iterate over the output of ls. Use `for key in Kexample.com*.key` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can type it at the bash prompt (command-line input, or CLI) and hit  after each line. Bash will keep track of it and send you to the next line where it will wait for your input after a > character as the prompt rather than a dollar or pound sign.

```
for key in $(ls Kexample.com*.key) <ENTER>
> do <ENTER>
> echo "\$INCLUDE $key">> example.com.zone <ENTER>
> done <ENTER>
```

After you press enter on the last line you'll get the output the command has available to it. Now then, some explanation:

- key is the variable that will be populated. That's why subsequent uses put a $-sign in front of it ($key)
- The use of the `\`-character is escaping what comes next, as in \$ so $INCLUDE isn't interpreted as a variable.
- `>>` means to append to the end of the file, example.come.zone
- `<ENTER>` is my way of telling you to press the return key.

I hope this helps. Now if you want to put it in a file and execute it as a command, there are a lot more things to consider, such as your $PATH variable, etc, etc.

Good luck with this new learning experience. I've been using Linux as my primary desktop OS for over 22 years now. Love it!

Comment: Thanks. Could you please look at my edit and inform me how to deal with `permission denied` output?

Comment: Before executing this script, become root.  There are a few ways to do this - if you are used to sudo, the easiest is to type "sudo /bin/bash" which will launch a new bash shell as root, thus giving you elevatated privileges until you exit it.